# Calling functions in swift

Tags: swift, function

So I am new to swift. I am trying to learn how to call functions. It seems pretty straight forward, but when trying to implement it I get all of these "Expected declaration error" I don't know what is the problem. I try putting in the viewDidLoad function, but whenever I do that when I put a delay or something like that, it automatically executes them without waiting. How do you correctly call the function? here is the code tell me what you think

```
func sayHello() { 
    print("Hello!")
} 
sayHello()
```

here Is a picture of context

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njOYT.png)

Comment: Show some context. Where is the code you posted in your question? Where is the error appearing exactly?

Comment: This code is correct. I would expect it to print "Hello!" Does it do something else?

Comment: *Expected declaration error* generally means: Put the calling code into a function / method.

Comment: from your image the `sayHello()` will never be ran, because it's NOT inside any function. It's only inside the declaration of your class and that's it. If you want something to always load from a viewController then it has to be in its `viewDidLoad`, for other classes it has to be within its `init` method.

Comment: Don't post your code as an image. Update your question with the actual, relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

In the `viewDidLoad()` method, you could call it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func sayHello() {
        print("Hello!")
    }
    sayHello()
}
```

or

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sayHello()
}

func sayHello() {
    print("Hello!")
}
```

When the view loads, this would print "Hello!" to the console in Xcode.

**EDIT:**

Based on your screenshot, you cannot call `sayHello()` that way because it will never be called in that context. When calling your functions, they need to be within some kind of "executable" context. That is, a defined code path that will eventually be executed.

Different application types may have different execution paths. An iOS app has other code that will need to be executed before getting to your code. Therefore, your code will need to be in place that Apple has defined (such as `viewDidLoad()`). If you do not do this, you will likely encounter compile time errors or undesired behaviour.

At the other end of the spectrum, if you simply create a file called `something.swift` and insert just the following code into that file:

```
func sayHello() {
    print("Hello!")
}
sayHello()
```

It will compile and run as expected.

Though it appears that the `sayHello()` call is not within any defined execution path, in the background the `sayHello()` function is called within a `main` function.

So at the very least, your function will be called from a `main` function. In more complex applications your function may be called within something else as defined by that application.

Understanding your application type (iOS, console, etc.) and its execution is essential for calling your functions.